# Complex number confussion

Tags: complex-numbers

We know that a complex number is represented by the form $a+ib$, where $a$, $b$ are two real numbers.
Now $2=2+i.0$
Then $2$ should be  a complex number.
So my statement is every real number is a complex number. Is the statement true?

Comment: Its true each real number is a complex number by the setting $r=r+i\cdot 0$.

Comment: By the way, number of the form $a + 0i$ is a real number.  A number of the form $0 + ai$ is a purely imaginary number.  It's a fun bit of trivia that $0$ is the only number that is both real *and* purely imaginary.... But I digress.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, every real number is a complex number.

Comment: But the real numbers can be compared to each other. As example 2>1. But the complex numbers can't be compared as they represent a point in the complex plane. So what's it?

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: @SahilLaskar As others have said, a property about a subset does not imply the same of a larger set. Reptiles lay eggs, but not all animals do...

Comment: @peterag I suspect the OP has heard, you *can't* have an order operation on the complex and interpreted it to mean you can't compare *any* complex numbers.   But the answer to that is you can compare *some* but not all complex numbers.  In your analogy this would be like saying.  "Animals don't all lay eggs" and interpreting to mean "No animal lay eggs".... and then when we are told "All reptiles lay eggs" we counter "..but reptiles are animals and you just said animals *don't* lay eggs".

Answer (score 2):

We can identify complex numbers of form $a+0i$ with real numbers $a$.

Comment: But the real numbers can be compared to each other. As example 2>1. But the complex numbers can't be compared as they represent a point in the complex plane. So what's it?

Comment: Properties of ordered sets need not to carry to the subsets. For example, order relation $<$ on $\mathbf{R}$ is dense (that is, for all $p<q$ there is $r$ st $p<r<q$), but it's not true for naturals, which can be regarded as a subset of reals, for $m$ and $m+1$ there is no natural $n$ st $m<n<m+1$.

Comment: What I'm saying, you can't endow $\mathbf{C}$ with order compatible with arithmetic operations, but while there is no such ordering for arbitrary complex numbers you can define a complete linear order (that is, "the same" as the order on reals) on some particular complex numbers, for instance on set of all numbers of form a+0i.

Answer (score 1):

$2$ *is*  complex number.  Just as natural numbers are is a subset integers which is a subset of the rationals which is a subset of the reals, the reals are a subset of the complex numbers.

In a comment you asked that the reals have an order relation and the complex don't.   That's actually fine.  If a set has a property that doesn't mean a *super*set will.     For a trivial example consider the set of even numbers.  Every even number is an integer.  Now every even number is divisible by $2$.  But it is not true that every integer is divisible by $2$.  Is that a contradiction?  Of course not.  Being divisible by $2$ is something every even number has but not every integer has.

> You commented: "But the real numbers can be compared to each other. As example 2>1. But the complex numbers can't be compared as they represent a point in the complex plane. So what's it? "

If the Complex numbers are represented as points in a plane, the Real numbers are represented as a subset as the point of a line in that plane.  We *can* compare points on a line by looking at which one is further in one direction than the other.  We can't do that for points in a plane.  We can say "this point has a greater absolute distance from zero than this point" but we can not compare two points that are the same distance but in different directions.

=====

Oh.....  I see your confusion.

It is not true that you can not compare *any* complex numbers.  It's just that *in general* you can compare *every* complex number.  You can obviously compare $4 + 0i > 2 + 0i$.  But you can not compare $2 + 0i$ to $0 + 6i$.

=====

Actually to get complicated, more complicated than is probably a good idea.  We *can* order and compare complex numbers.  We can say $a + bi > c + di$ if $a > c$ or if $a=c$ and $b> d$.  This is called the lexicographic order; we compare first the real part and if equal we then compare the imaginary part (but only if the real parts are equal).  *BUT* this order does not have algebraic properties.  If $x > y$ and $z > 0$ that we would no longer be able to say $xz > yz$.  Of if $x > 0$ and $y> 0$ that would no longer be able to say that $xy > 0$.  And without those properties this order just isn't *useful* to us.

Comment: If every element of a set has a property (such as the reals have order) then all the elements of the subsets (such as the naturall numbers, or the rationals) will to
Not true. As I mentioned in a comment, ordered set $(\mathbb{R},<)$ is dense, but it's subset $(\mathbb{N},<)$ is not. $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, but $\mathbb{R}$, regarded as a subset of $\mathbb{C}$, is not.

Comment: Argh... good point.  I'll try to find a better wording.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, every real number is also a complex number.** Real numbers, denoted by $\mathbb{R}$, are proper subset of complex numbers (denoted by $\mathbb{C}$). Every real number, say $ x$, can be expressed in the general form of complex numbers, which is $ x + iy$, where x represents the real part whereas y represents the imaginary part of the complex number.

$\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{W} \subset \mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R} \subset\mathbb{C}$.

**Also, remember that** real numbers can be compared to each other (e.g., $5>2$), but in the case of complex numbers, we cannot compare them. Even $3+2i$ and $2+2i$ cannot be compared.

*That's a brief introduction about complex numbers.*